# Check if the input number is in a valid binary format

Tags: java, binary

i tried to make a simple program,which check if the input number from the user is a binary number and that number is in correct binary format  -> without leading zeros. That below is my code,but it doesn't work. I would appreciate if someone could help.

```
    public class CheckNumberBinary {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int r = 0, c = 0, num, b;

        Scanner sl = new Scanner(System.in);
        num = sl.nextInt();
       int firstDigit = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(num).substring(0, 1));// i want to get the first digit from the input
        if (firstDigit>0||firstDigit==1 ){
            while (num > 0) {
                if ((num % 10 == 0) || (num % 10 == 1))
                    c++;
                r++;
                num = num / 10;
            }
            if (c == r) {
                System.out.println(true);
            } else
                System.out.println(false);
        } else System.out.printf("WARNING: The number starts with 0");
    }
}
```

Comment: What does not work? What do you expect to happen and what do you get?

Comment: can you share test data

Comment: Hint: rename your variables so that someone else does not have to guess what they are for.

Comment: When i input 0001 the programm return true. Test: 10100 -> True ; 0001 - > False; 8123->False

Comment: `if(firstDigit>0||firstDigit==1)` this condition should be `if(firstDigit==1)` because other than `1` as a first digit should surely return false. This will solve your problem.

Comment: you are getting input as an integer, so java removes leading zeroes. so get input as string then check for leading zeroes

Comment: what did you mean by `When i input 0001 the programm return true. Test: 10100 -> True ; 0001 - > False; 8123->False` why you said `0001` return true in the beginning and return false in the end?????????? what you want exactly true for 0001 or false?

Comment: @YCF_L 0001 musst be false,but in my example it is true.That is what i want to change

Comment: ok check my answer in bottom

Comment: Check my answer, I updated it. Should work fine to you, let me know if it useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a better solution, you can check if your input contain only 0 and 1 and the input great then 0 then valide number, so instead you can use String for example :

```
String num;
Scanner sl = new Scanner(System.in);
num = sl.next();
if (num.matches("[01]+") && !num.startsWith("0")) {
    System.out.println("Correct number :" + num);
}else{
    System.out.println("Not Correct number!");
}
```

---

1. `num.matches("[01]+")` will check if your input contain only 0 and 1.
2. `!num.startsWith("0")` this to answer this part **without leading zeros**

---

**Test:**

```
10010     -> Correct number :10010
00001     -> Not Correct number!
11101     -> Correct number :01101
98888     -> Not Correct number!
```

Comment: For example i want to 'catch' all numbers,who starts with 0?How i can do that?

Comment: @DeanTwit you can use startWith like `if(num.startsWith("0")){
    System.out.println("Start by 0");
}`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)

Comment: What about the ***without leading zeros*** part? Is it not required anymore?

Comment: what did you mean @BackSlash i don't get you?

Comment: @YCF_L The question states: *i tried to make a simple program,which check if the input number from the user is a binary number and that number is in correct binary format ->* ***without leading zeros*** - Your answer doesn't fulfill that requirement, so my question was to the OP: Did requirements change? Why is this the accepted answer?

Comment: check the op [Comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43980769/check-if-the-input-number-is-in-a-valid-binary-format/43981141?noredirect=1#comment74990701_43980769) @BackSlash

Comment: OP also wants to check if there exists leading zeros or not. He just gave an example of it by `0001`. It should also work for other than this number say `0101`.

Comment: @YCF_L Yeah I've read the comments - I intended it as an example. I think the OP was just saying "For 0001 it should say false, because it starts with 0" - not because it is 0001. That's why I'm asking if requirements changed. I don't understand. I didn't downvote BTW, I just want to understand why the OP accepts an answer which doesn't fulfill the requirements written in the question.

Comment: ok @SanketMakani i already edit my answer and correct this problem

Comment: @BackSlash check my answer now

Comment: @BackSlash that was my mistake(for checking the best answer).I''m really sorry for that. Your answer with regex is really good,too.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
     boolean binary=true;  // boolean for final decision
     String input; 
     int counter=0; // to count how many leading zeros there are in the input
     int target = 5; // specify how many leading zeros allowed!!

     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     input = in.nextLine(); // take the entire line as a String

    //first loop through the whole input to check for any illegal entry (i.e. non digits)
    for(char digit : input.toCharArray()){
         if(!Character.isDigit(digit)){ // catch any non-digit !
            System.out.println("Illegal Input Found!"); // inform user and exit
            System.exit(0);
         }
         if(digit!='0' && digit!='1'){ // check if it's not 1 and not 0
               binary = false;
         }
    }

    // now if there are no illegal inputs, check if it starts with leading zeros 
    if(input.charAt(0)=='0'){ // potential leading zeros, check the rest
       while(input.charAt(counter)=='0'){ // while there are followed zeros
            counter++;
            if(counter>target && binary){ // leading zeros only in case it's a binary
                System.out.println("Illegal Leading Zeros!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
     }


    // now if your program reach this point that means the input is valid and doesn't contain leading zeros in case it's a binary
    if(binary){
       System.out.println("It is a binary number");
    }
    else{
         System.out.println("It is NOT a binary number");
    }
}
```

**Test:**

```
01010101  ->  It is a binary number
01010105  ->  It is NOT a binary number
0000001   ->  Illegal Leading Zeros!
0000005   ->  It is NOT a binary number
000000A   ->  Illegal Input Found!
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use the standard library methods?

```
static boolean isValidBinary(final int input) {
    final String binary = String.valueOf(input);

    return binary.replaceAll("[01]", "").isEmpty() && !binary.startsWith("0");
}
```

Comment: Why use standard library methods to create non-standard, hard to read, overly complex code to solve a trivial problem? Besides, I'm sure he's writing a homework solution.

Comment: For a basic homework like this I don't think regex is the right answer. Probably the OP doesn't even know what they are. And even with regexes, this can be just solved with `return binary.matches("0[01]+")`

Comment: @Kayaman You find OP's code easier to read than those two lines?

Comment: No, but compared to a proper solution like the one @BackSlash posted, yours is almost as bad as the OP's.

Comment: Yeah, not really. Be rational.

Comment: No, really. You use regex to replace characters...then checking if the result is empty. You're trying to be too clever for your own good.

Comment: BTW it should be `return binary.matches("1[01]+")` - misread the question, my bad

Comment: @Kayaman Well I'm trying to be clever for the sake of readability and simplicity. That's what coding is all about, no?

Comment: Well you failed. Not a very clever idea to modify the input when you just want to know if it matches a certain format.

Comment: Where did I modify the input?

Answer (score 0):

you should not use `sl.nextInt();`  it will transfer '011' to 11, so when user input '011', the variable 'num' get the int value 11. 
You should simply use `sl.next()` to get the input of user.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check your "if" condition before the while, because you don't want that the number starts with 0, right? so... just ask for it, I have tryied and worded fine to me:

```
public class CheckNumberBinary {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int r = 0, c = 0, num, b;

        Scanner sl = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = sl.next();
        num = Integer.parseInt(input);
        String firstDigit = (input.length() > 0 ? input.substring(0, 1) : "" );
        if (firstDigit.equals("0")) {
            System.out.printf("WARNING: The number starts with 0");
        } else {

            while (num > 0) {
                if ((num % 10 == 0) || (num % 10 == 1))
                    c++;
                r++;
                num = num / 10;
            }
            if (c == r) {
                System.out.println(true);
            } else
                System.out.println(false);
        }
    }

}
```

The rest of your code Fulfills its mission! It tells you if the number is binary or not, and now plus tells you if your code begins with useless zeros

Answer (score 0):

```
   import java.util.*;

   public class BinaryTest {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

        int count=0;
        boolean check=true;

        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        int num=input.nextInt();

        for(int i=0; i<=num; i++){
            count=num%10;
            if(count>1) {
                check=false;
            break;
            }
            else {
                check=true;
            }

            num=num/10;
        }
        if(check)
            System.out.println("Binary");
        else
            System.out.println("Not Binary");
    }
}
```